# No more sound after running Ardour

Tags: jack, ardour

All the sound works perfect with all the applications on my system. But from the moment I launch Ardour, no more sound comes out from other application than Ardour. The easy way to get it back is to restart the laptop.

This is probably related to Jack ... but it's not clear...

Does anyone know what's going on behind the scene? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

in Terminal:`$ top | grep jackd`, first number in line will be the pid of JACK, kill it with `$ kill <pid>`. It's the simplest way)

Comment: What about `pkill` or `pgrep` instead of `top|grep`? ;)

Comment: As @0xC0000022L suggested  `pkill -9 jackd` also works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am still figuring out jack and ardour, but you probably need to stop jack. I use qjackctl which you can find in the software center (if you don't already have it installed). after you finished with ardour hit stop in qjackctl and in my system normal sounds start working again.

Comment: That is not enough ... still no sound!

Answer (score 0):

Theres probably a more hygienic method, but opening up the task manager and killing the jackd process fixed the same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

After intalling adour I got no sound from my speakers. In “Sound preferences”, in the “sound output” tab, select “analog audio output”, and I got sound.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a bridge to pulseaudio, to get all audio passed over to jack.

You might have to install the following package first, like

`$ sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-jack`

Then you can add the module with:

`$ pactl load-module module-jack-sink`

If you enable
[jack dbus interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4hxi.png) in the jack settings
you can also add

`$ pactl load-module module-jackdbus-detect`

This will enable pulseaudio to automatically load the jack-sink and jack-source modules as soon as jack is started.

The last step is to set the **sound device** in your **system settings** to `JACK sink (PulseAudio Jack Sink)` and JACK source for input.

For more information, see: [pulse audio jack connectivity modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#jackconnectivitymodules)

Answer (score -1):

Just to share the way I wrote the command to kill `jackd`:

```
sudo killall jackd
```

Comment: Hello!  This would be better suited as a comment posted upon the answer which suggests to kill the `jackd` process rather than as its own answer.  As you have the comment privilege, you should be able to add a comment to the other answer that suggests killing `jackd` by using the "add a comment" button underneath the other comments on that answer.